# Serve angular assets from a specific url

Tags: angular, assets, cdn

I have a website (powered by Angular 9 and Universal), which is served from a domain. I want the assets to be served by our asset provider, instead of our current universal express server.

- `https://{{locale}}.domain.com` is the main entrypoint for our app
- `https://somecdn.com/folder/{{locale}}` is the main entrypoint for our assets

It means if we have this kind of asset locally:

```
app/
  somechunk.js
  assets/
    style.css
```

Then it should be served from the urls

```
https://assets.otherdomain.com/app/{{locale}}/assets/style.css
https://assets.otherdomain.com/app/{{locale}}/somechunk.js
```

I tried few things with `baseHref` without success. Don't know if it's possible with some angular options, or if I should add some custom build step to update these url...

Any idea? Thanks a lot

---

PS: some useful resource I run into while searching for a solution to this issue:

- https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/pull/16332
- https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/17737
- https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/design/deployurl-basehref.md

Comment: Was you able to get this done?

Comment: Hey, I left the company few weeks after. But I can ask my collegues if they succeed @ErnestoAlfonso ;)

Comment: Yes, because this is an important issue for the micro frontend architecture. It would be great

Comment: I've aked them ;)

Comment: Hey, so finally it looks like we hosted it on the same domain, but on a different subdomain. `domain.com` for the website and `assets.domain.com` for the assets. Hope it'll help.

Comment: OK, thanks, I think this is not enough, I'll keep searching thanks